# How to prove that the function $f:(0,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=e^x\cdot \ln (x) -x^e$ have a unique zero?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I need to proof that the function 
$$f(x)=e^x\cdot \ln (x) -x^e$$
have a unique zero $x=e$, where $e=2.71828...$ (the Euler's number). It's true because the graphic has a unique intercept whith the horizontal axis in the cartesian plane. But I need of an analitical proof, if she exists. Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Functions don't have solutions, equations have solutions. But it seems like you mean the equation $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes, I expressed myself badly, I want to get the zeros of the function, i.e. the points $x$ where $f(x)=0$...

Comment: Hint: What is the derivative of $f$?

Answer (score 3):

$\ln(e)=1$ hence $f(e)=e^e-e^e=0$, so $x=e$ clearly works.

As $x\to \infty, e^x\to \infty, \ln(x) \to \infty$ (albeit slower) , and $x^e<e^x$ for $x>e$ and $0<x<e$, hence the function $f(x)=e^x\ln(x)-x^e>0$ $\forall x>e$.

In terms of having a solution from $0<x<e$: $0<x<1$ is impossible because $\ln(x)<0$ while $e^x, x^e>0$, so $f(x)<0$.

For $1<x<e, \ln(x)<1$, which means that $x^e>e^x\ln(x)$ and  $f(x)<0$

You can check $f(1)$ to show that doesn't work either.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries. Was a  nice mental exercise